# Issue with SQL Trigger old and new values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

Here is my (in progress) trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgInsertUpdate]
ON [dbo].[joinreason]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @jr_active AS char(1), @jrid AS int;
    SELECT @jr_active = (SELECT jr_active FROM INSERTED)
    SELECT @jrid = (SELECT jrid FROM INSERTED)

    IF UPDATE(jr_active)
    BEGIN
        IF (jr_active = 'N')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE joinreason
            SET jr_active = 'N' where jr_par_jrid = jrid;
        END
    END
END
```

The jr_active column is a 'Y' or 'N'. 
The business requirements are:

When a record is has no jr_par_id, it is considered a parent.

When a record has a jr_par_id, it is considered a child.

1. The jr_par_id of a child == jrid of the parent

When a parent's jr_active column is changed from 'Y' to 'N':

1. All children should be updated to be 'N' in the jr_active column

I am having trouble understanding how to reference the old values(those that were changed after update) and the new values (those that are to be updated).

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Please keep in mind that a trigger is set-based! The code you have right now won't function correctly when multiple rows are updated in `joinreason`.

Comment: No more than one row will ever be updated at a given time.

Comment: If more than one row is inserted then your trigger will throw error.

Comment: That may be true from an application perspective but don't let yourself get caught in that mindset. The time can and will come that a multiple row update will happen and with this trigger your data will get mangled. Fix your trigger so it can handle multiple rows from the get go. A friend of mine worked as a consultant for a company that went under because their triggers didn't handle multiple rows.

Comment: @NickCarfagno How long is `ever`? But it is possible, right? So shouldn't you take this into account?

Comment: Understood. Good points. Anyone have an idea as to how I would update the logic to account for multiple rows?

Comment: How many levels can there be in the hierarchy, i.e. can a record *either* be a parent *or* a child, or can a record be both?

Comment: Parent or child. Parents cannot be children, children cannot be parents.

Comment: Is this a hierarchy or a simple parent-child? Some ddl and sample data for this table would make an answer pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers that fires after update have access to two virtual tables: `inserted` which contains the new updated version of the changed rows, and `deleted` which contains the old version (before the update) of the changed rows. To have a trigger detect if a row has changed you need to join both virtual tables and compare the value of interest.

I believe this trigger is what you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgInsertUpdate]
ON [dbo].[joinreason]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(jr_active)
    BEGIN
       UPDATE joinreason 
       SET jr_active = 'N' 
       FROM joinreason j
       JOIN inserted i ON i.jrid = j.jr_par_jrid
       JOIN deleted d  ON i.jrid = d.jrid
       WHERE d.jr_active = 'Y' AND i.jr_active = 'N'
    END
END
```

The join with the `inserted` virtual table limits the update to children and the join with `deleted` filters out the parent rows that had its `jr_active` changed from `Y` to `N`.

if you want to test it my test code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/GzVjX4dT

Comment: Thank you so much. Not only did you provide a working solution, but you explained how it works. Awesome.